Why do Catholics believe that the dead can be saved when the Bible states otherwise?
This question is directed to followers of the Catholic Faith, why do they believe that the dead can still be saved if we intercede for them when scripture explicity states that it is appointed for men to live once after which death and judgment follow.
Hebrews 9:27

And just as it is appointed for man to die once, and after that comes judgment

I interpret the verse above to mean that after we die then there is nothing we can do to either glorify or provoke God and that is why we await judgment for works done while in the body.
The story of the rich man and Lazarus also shows that the dead can't be saved because the rich man would have applauded to Abraham to intercede for him to enter into life but that didn't happen, the brothers of the rich man were the ones who were still in the world and their hearts were hardened against the prophets and the oracles, which mean that you can still be saved while still in the world and not when you have departed from it. Why do Catholics believe so?

"The story of the rich man and Lazarus also shows that the dead can't be saved". This story is a metaphor, not something that defines doctrine.
The CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: Lazarus indicates that this is a parable, not to be taken literally.

In "and after that comes judgment", "judgment" is not the same as "condemnation". Various scriptures talk of resurrection, and Revelation 20 and 21 speak of a "second death" (for those that are condemned).

@RayButteworth, while alive we can make God happy or anger Him wit our actions after we die then we cannot be saved because we know nothing because Ecclesiastes tbe priest said the dead know nothing

Agreed, the Bible says that the dead are unconscious, but that following resurrection they will be conscious. But this is getting away from the requested Catholic view.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Perhaps this might help! https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/is-it-possible-to-repent-after-death-in-catholicism Or this comment. The Catholic Church says no. For example, the Catechism teaches, “there is no repentance for men after death,” and bases this teaching on the irrevocable character that man's choice takes on after the soul separates from the body—similar to that of the angels (CCC 393).

You seem to think that the souls in purgatory can be saved by our intercession. They are already saved; their salvation does not change after death. Our intercession can shorten the time needed for their purification in purgatory, but they are already sure of eventually getting to heaven. (Souls in hell, on the other hand, cannot be helped.)

@AndreasBlass, so there are souls in purgatory according to Catholics, is purgatory the temporary heaven?

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=Catholic+prayers+for+the+dead

Don’t Catholics believe there is no death of the soul?

"the rich man would have applauded to Abraham to intercede" only if the Rich man were a virtuous man, which the story implies he was not. Further, hell is not purgatory.

This question is already answered here I think: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/is-it-possible-to-repent-after-death-in-catholicism

This question seems to misunderstand the Catholic doctrine on purgatory. According to Catholic doctrine, there are three possible states of a soul that has been separated from the body (the definition of anthropological death) and been subsequently judged. The judgement happens instantaneously upon death.

The soul may be guilty of unrepented mortal sins. This soul goes to hell eternally.
The soul may be perfectly clean, having repented of all sins, mortal and venial, and done sufficient penances for all sins. This soul would go directly to heaven. This almost never happens, because while many Christians repent of all mortal sins and are thus saved, very few have even repented of all venial sins, much less done sufficient penances.
The soul may be totally repented of all mortal sins, but only more or less repentant of some or all venial sins, and has not done sufficient penance in any case. Such a soul is consigned for a time to purgatory, where it undergoes a temporary, painful purification that prepares it to enter heaven eternally. Every single soul in purgatory is guaranteed to be in heaven eventually, and to share in eternal bliss. This will happen whether we pray for such souls or not.

Regarding souls in purgatory, the Catholic Church teaches that we, the faithful on Earth, may pray for them. The purpose of our prayers for those in purgatory is for them to more quickly enter heaven. Thus, we ease their suffering by our prayers. The Church teaches that it is futile to pray for a soul in hell, but She also does not definitively place any soul in hell. Because of this, a faithful Christian may pray for any deceased soul conditionally, that condition being that the soul is actually in purgatory.
This is mostly common knowledge, at least among Catholics, but here is a Catholic Answers article on purgatory for further reading.

Please look at the answer to this question: I think you didn't search the site very well. Try to check next time please. :)
Is it possible to repent after death in Catholicism?
It seems to answer everything from the catholic side. I have a slightly different view, but it falls in the realm of the unknowable anyways.
